# Consumer group with no active consumers / Automatic group deletion

Tags: apache-kafka

I wanted to know if "old" groups are deleted by Kafka automatically (After retention time expires) ?
I see on StackOverFlow this anwser for similar question but didn't find anything about that on Confluent documentation .

> Do nothing and wait offsets.retention.minutes. This settings defaults
> to 7 days. Groups without any members for this duration are
> automatically deleted. This mechanism exists since Kafka 0.8.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are deleted automatically after `offsets.retention.minutes`. It basically sets the retention time of the `__consumer_offsets` internal Kafka topic, where the consumer group offsets are stored.

The Confluent documentation describes this setting https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#brokerconfigs_offsets.retention.minutes

Comment: The problem is then the Clean Policiy setting will decide if Kafka will compact or delete the offset and it seems that by deault , the internal topic __consumer_Offsets is set to compact.

Comment: `__consumer_offsets` is always a compacted topic and even when compacted, old messages are deleted following the topic retention time setting.

Comment: In version 2.4 +: Compact policy won't delete the message . You need to mix both policies to make the segment eligible for deletion => [ompact,delete] policies is then required